# Disable horizontal scroll in the Source of RStudio

Tags: view, scroll, rstudio

how do I disable the horizontal scroll in the Source of Rstudio? In a way that when the code excedes the window width, it appears in a new line automatically? The line number in that case should't appear.

here is how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did :

Tools -- Global options -- Code -- clic on "Soft Wrap code"

[image]

Comment: thanks @alexis it worked! it was super easy :D :D