# Cannot soft wrap R source files in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, word-wrap

I'm having trouble soft wrapping .R source files in the text editor in Rstudio Version 1.4.1717. I have tried to follow advice given online but it dosn't seem to change anything on my screen. It seems it should be fairly simple using the advice here:
[Disable horizontal scroll in the Source of RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438974/disable-horizontal-scroll-in-the-source-of-rstudio)
and here:
[wrap code in R Studio text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901028/wrap-code-in-r-studio-text-editor)

I have tried various things like ticking and unticking "soft wrap R source files check box", selecting all text in the text editor before re-trying, closing and restarting Rstudio etc...but still doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I'm missing something really obvious?!

**Update:** I managed to get it working if I start a new file (File > New File > R script). Please see here:
[R studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELme1.jpg)

However, this does not seem to work for R scripts that I had already created. The bottom right of the source window, does indeed say "R Script".

**Update 2**
I managed to get this working if I copy pasted the entire R script to a new file ((File > New File > R script), as opposed to re-saving the current file as a newer version (using File > Save As...")
When I went to save the file, a pop-up box appeared which asked me "Choose Encoding" for which I selected the default. I wonder if the previous file had a different encoding which meant the text wrapping could not work properly? Strangely, much earlier versions of the file did NOT have any problems when when using the wrap text functionality. So it seems that something happened to one of the recent versions that is causing the issue.

Comment: It works for me, though I'm only using 1.4.1103.  One thing I'd check is whether R thinks your file is R source code:  that's indicated in the bottom right of the source window, as "R Script".  I wouldn't expect soft wrapping to apply to other file types.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have provided an update in my question.

Comment: tell us the version you are working with>

Comment: No idea what's going wrong for you.  I just updated to  1.4.1717, and it's fine.  As I change that setting, the soft wrapping changes for old files as well as new ones.  In case it makes a difference, I'm running RStudio locally on MacOS.

Comment: What platform are you on, and do you have RStudio running locally, or on a server?

Comment: Windows 10.  Rstudio running locally.

Comment: Do you still have any of the files that trigger this issue?  Do you know what encoding they are using?  One possible way to get a strange encoding is to open the file in a different editor that saves it differently.

Comment: Yes I still have the files that trigger the issue (unfortunately I am unable to share). I'm not sure if there is something I need to check about the file properties itself?  The system default is ISO-8859-1 (checked with File>Save with Encoding...)

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember to click `apply` before the `ok` button after checking the box?

[image: Do these:]

You need not restart RStudio to get the change effected.

Comment: Thank you for the clear diagram. I did indeed use these steps. However, the text wrapping does still not work for some R scripts (older versions of my current one). I think it might be something to do with encoding (please see update 2)

Comment: For me, Apply isn't needed.  The difference between OK and Apply is just that OK closes the dialog, whereas Apply makes the change but leaves the dialog open.

Comment: Restart your PC let's see what will happen?

Comment: Tell me the version of RStudio you are working with?

Comment: It is on the first line of my question :) ... Rstudio Version 1.4.1717.